# Decoding dtmf from sound card

Tags: linux, audio, sound-card, phone

I'm trying to decode DTMF (phone tones) from my linux sound card.
I tried to use multimon. But when I run "multimon -a DTMF" as it says in the documentation, it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to use "multimon", or any other program that works the same in linux?

```
$ multimon -a DTMF
multimod  (C) 1996/1997 by Tom Sailer HB9JNX/AE4WA
available demodulators: POCSAG512 POCSAG1200 POCSAG2400 EAS AFSK1200 AFSK2400 AFSK2400_2 HAPN4800 FSK9600 DTMF ZVEI CCIR SCOPE
Enabled demodulators: DTMF
open: No such file or directory
```

When I run "strace -e file multimon -a DTMF 2>&1 | grep ENOENT", this is the output:

```
$ strace -e file multimon -a DTMF 2>&1 | grep ENOENT
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/dsp", O_RDONLY)              = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Can you run `strace -e file multimon -a DTMF 2>&1 | grep ENOENT`?

Comment: I added the output to the question. It's useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, multimon-ng which is the successor to multimon works well for demodulating DTMF.

```
$ multimon-ng -a DTMF
multimon-ng 1.1.8
  (C) 1996/1997 by Tom Sailer HB9JNX/AE4WA
  (C) 2012-2019 by Elias Oenal
Available demodulators: POCSAG512 POCSAG1200 POCSAG2400 FLEX EAS UFSK1200 CLIPFSK FMSFSK AFSK1200 AFSK2400 AFSK2400_2 AFSK2400_3 HAPN4800 FSK9600 DTMF ZVEI1 ZVEI2 ZVEI3 DZVEI PZVEI EEA EIA CCIR MORSE_CW DUMPCSV X10 SCOPE
Enabled demodulators: DTMF
DTMF: 5
DTMF: 6
DTMF: 8
```